# how to call more than 1 batch files in a vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am using the following code to call a batch file:

```
dim shell  
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")  
shell.run "a.bat D:\a"  
set shell=nothing
```

How do I call more than 1 batch file, so that when the 1st file's execution is over the 2nd file is executed.
as always, I really appreciate any help offered.

Comment: what is it in your batch that you can't do directly in vbscript?

Comment: Possibly it's a third party, or legacy, tool that isn't worth rewriting.

Comment: in my batch files i am calling command line to copy files and zip them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below

```
shell.run "a.bat D:\a"
```

add another line with another

```
shell.run "b.bat ...."
```

Or create a batch file that calls all the other batch files, and call that batch file from your script.

Comment: my a .bat looks like:  
D:  
cd D:\d  
winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a  
my c.bat looks like:
xcopy D:\d D:\o /E
my b.bat looks like:
call a.bat  
call c.bat  
when i execute b.bat,it calls a. bat but not c.bat

Comment: do the batch files work independently? ie manually run a.bat and then c.bat.

Comment: when i execute c.bat(xcopy D:\d D:\o /E) it prompts to enter d( for directory) or f (for files). may b that is causing the problem. how do i eliminate this prompting and set d(directory) as default

Comment: fixed the prompting problem used a "\" after destination path. but still it does not work if called simultaneously.but if i call the xcopy file first and then zippping file then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Option explicit

Dim oShell

set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.Run "RunAs /noprofile /user:Admininistrator ""%comspec% /c 1stcommand && 2ndcommand && 3rdcommand""", 1, false

WScript.Sleep 1000

oShell.Sendkeys "AdmininistratorPassword~"

Wscript.Quit